# Javascript não pega array alterado antes do click

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, click

Tenho um código click:

```
var layerMap = [];

$(document).on('click', '#TipoMapa', function(){

    console.log(layerMap);

});
```

E tenho um código que altera a variável **layerMap**:

```
$(document).on('click', '#tipo', function(){
    layerMap['regional'] = layerMap['regional'] || [];
    layerMap['regional'] = 'Alisson';
});
```

O que acontece é que clico no botão que cria um array em `layerMap` e após isso, clico no botão para dar o `console.log` na variável `layerMap`, mas o conteúdo sempre está me retornando como `[]`, ou seja, vazio. O que pode ser?

Comment: so pra confirmar voce clica no botao com id `#tipo` e depois clica no botao com id `#TipoMapa` e nesse ponto o `layerMap` ainda esta vazio certo?

Comment: voce esta tentando acessar uma propriedade de um array, nao desejaria um objeto ao inves de um array?

Comment: sim, segundo o JS sim, mas se eu dou um console.log após criar o array na função do click `#tipo` ele retorna o array. Mas se clico no `#tipo` ele da como vazio

Comment: pode ser um monte de coisa, pode postar um pouco mais do seu js e o html ou se possivel reproduzir o seu problema no jsfiddle

Answer (score 2):

Quando você tenta escrever uma variável no console, o que vai para o console é o resultado da chamada de `.toString()` no que você passou.

Para arrays, o resultado de `.toString()` é equivalente à chamada de `.join()`, [segundo a documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString):

> Implementado no JavaScript 1.8.5 (Firefox 4), e compatível com a 5ª versão do ECMAScript, a função toString() é genérica e pode ser usada em qualquer Objeto. Se o objeto tem um método join(), ele será chamado e esse valor será devolvido.

O importante saber é que `.join()` retorna os elementos do Array, separados por vírgula. Mas você não colocou nenhum elemento no Array.

## Epa

#### como assim não coloquei nenhum elemento no Array?

Essa sintaxe:

```
layerMap['regional'] = layerMap['regional'] || [];
```

É sintaxe de objeto. Você adicionou uma propriedade ao Array, chamada "regional", mas uma propriedade é uma coisa. Um elemento é outra.

Então, de duas uma:

- Ou você passa a usar índices numéricos ao invés de strings, e aí layerMap se comportará como você esperava...
- Ou você faz com que layerMap seja um objeto ao invés de Array, e assim as propriedades aparecerão no console.

Basta fazer assim:

```
var layerMap = {};
```

Answer (score -1):

Infelizmente, diferente de outras linguagens como PHP, Python, etc...

O Javascript não aceita chave nomeada como você fez neste exemplo: 
layerMap['regional'].

Ele aceita apenas chaves numérias.
Caso você queira chaves nomeadas, tente trabalhar com objetos, pois arrays não serão sua melhor opção para chavear.

Aconselho olhar no w3schools mais sobre Arrays Javascript:

[Arrays em javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)

Comment: O incrível é que ele cria o array certinho. Dentro do click do `#tipo` após criar o array dou um console.log e ele retorna o array certinho. Mas se eu clicar em `#TipoMapa` ele fala que está vazio.

Comment: Javascript aceita chave nomeada. É uma forma de se criar e acessar propriedades em objetos. Inclusive o código do AP roda sem erros, pois a propriedade é criada corretamente no Array.

Comment: Justamente por quê ele internamente, transforma sua chave em numérica. Ele não reconhece e tenta converter. Quando você vai buscar, não encontra nada. Tenta associar um numero a um tipo de informação, tipo: região 1, estado 2, cidade 3, e assim você consegue ir definindo.

Comment: Acho que não @Renan. Olhe a documentação do JavaScript, ele a respeito disso acusa um warning.

Comment: @DávilAndré Não. Além de não haver nada na documentação sobre isso, você pode experimentar no seu ambiente favorito: `'use strict'; var arr = []; arr['foo'] = 'bar'`. Nem em modo estrito isso dá erro ;)

Comment: Funciounou de fato @Renan. Estranho é que no site ele fala a respeito disso: WARNING !!
If you use named indexes, JavaScript will redefine the array to a standard object.
After that, some array methods and properties will produce incorrect results. Não entendo.

Comment: @DávilAndré esse aviso é do W3Schools. O W3Schools é o pior lugar do mundo para se aprender a programar (o SO em inglês vive falando mal de lá), mas assim como um relógio parado, até o W3S tá certo ao menos uma vez por dia. Misturar sintaxe de Array e objeto na mesma variável é pedir para sofrer, porque aí você perde qualquer garantia de que aquele array vai se comportar sempre como Array. A decisão de como ele vai se comportar cabe à quem for implementar o ambiente, então você pode ter resultados diferentes em navegadores diferentes, por exemplo.